# Turning cache off on a production environment.

Tags: full-page-cache, redis, cm-redissession, ee-1.14.2.4

What are the main cons of disabling all of magento's FPC?

If i temporarily turn them off will anything severe result?

Same question for redis?

Currently I'm having an issue with my caching but I'm not sure if the problem is redis or magento FPC. I'm planning on turning of the native FPC for a couple hours this evening. Should I expect anything horrific?

Answer (score 0):

It will slow down website loading speed. Besides that, It won't cause any serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mark told is correct. All Static and CMS are loading slow down.

What are the blocks are cache cacheable are also slow down. other than that any major serious will not occurs. but it will affect performance.